# Netsuite - Set Line Item Value

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to figure out how to set a custom value item from the value of another field on the item field. I am not getting any errors, but it is not changing the value.

Here is the code:

```
function validatePOLineItem(type){
   if(type == 'item'){
     for (var i = 0; i <= nlapiGetLineItemCount('item'); i++) {
     // Get the value for amount on the item line
     var amount = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'amount');
     // Get the value for the PO Amount on the item line
     var po_amount = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_po_amount');
     // Set PO Amount equal to Amount on the item line
     nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', po_amount, amount);
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you left off the column name you are trying to set. Also, you should just have to update the "current" line…

```
function validatePOLineItem(type){
  if(type == 'item'){
    var amount = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'amount');
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_po_amount', amount);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a client side script or a user event script?  If it is a client side script that is deployed on the validate line event, then you do not need to do a loop.  Since the function will trigger every time a line is added.  Also you will need to add 'return true' as the last line for the line to be added.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate the `amount` field programmatically. You need to modify the quantity or the rate instead. If you are trying to apply a discount or something like that, then I recommend using NetSuite's Discount Items or Promo Codes mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think my code is correct in trying to modify the custom field PO Amount to be equal to Amount for each item line.

Comment: I misread your intent. Your code is actually not correct then. Aaron Hinni's comment is correct. Right now your code reads something like: `nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 54.00, 54.00)` because you are using the value of the custom Amount field for the field ID.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Why do you need to have a loop if you are just dealing with the current line item?

Suggested Solution: If you want to achieve it, you can set the Rate equal to `'custcol_po_amount'` but this will only work if the quantity is 1 and assuming that the value on `'custcol_po_amount'` is accurate.

Comment: In the case where there are multiple lines on a Purchase Order, I need the value on each line for the custom field PO Amount to be the same as Amount. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to have loop. You can have your script executed on field change or recalc function of a client script so you don't need to iterate.

Comment: code for field change
function fieldChange(type, name, lineum){
   if(type == 'item' &&  name == 'custcol_po_amount'){
     //do your thing
   }
 }

code for recalc
function recacl(type){
 if(type == 'item'){
  //do your thing
 }
}